# add new header column to .csv file using powershell

Tags: loops, powershell, csv

I'm trying to add a new header column to a .csv file with using powershell. When this is done the next step is to fill all data columns with the same entry it should look like this:

Before:

```
Name;Kind;Type1;Type2;Type3;
Function1;Method;something1;something1;something1;
Function2;Method;something1;something1;something1;
```

After:

```
Name;Kind;Type1;Type2;Type3;Version
Function1;Method;something1;something1;something1;1
Function2;Method;something1;something1;something1;1
```

So because of the file has ~35 columns and ~30000 rows i need to loop through
But i dont know how to get to the end of a line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this:

```powershell
$inFile = "C:\path\to\your\file.csv"
$outFile = "C:\path\to\your\modifications.csv"
$v = Import-Csv -Delimiter ';' $inFile
$v | % { $_ | Add-Member -NotePropertyName "Version" -NotePropertyValue 1 }
$v | ConvertTo-Csv -Delimiter ';' -NoTypeInformation | Out-File $outFile
```

Import the csv file to a powershell object, then iterate over all the lines and use the `Add-Member` cmdlet to add an extra property.

Then convert the object back to csv format and save to a new file. You can of course overwrite the original file with this, but be careful the information is correct before you do it.